# Test for the number of elements using Jasmine in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am writing an end to end test using Jasmine for AngularJS.  I am using Protractor to run the test.  I have the following markup

```
<ul class="phone-thumbs">
  <li ng-repeat="img in phone.images">
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to test that for a particular page instance I have four of these images.  Here's what I have so far

```
describe('Phone detail view', function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('app/index.html#/phones/nexus-s');
    });

    it('should display four thumbnails on the nexus-s page', function() {
      expect(element(by.css('.phone-thumbs li img')).length()).toBe(4);
    });
  });
```

Problem is that I get an error saying

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'length'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*This question is part of the Experiments section in [tutorial 8](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_08) of the AngularJS tutorial.*

Here is how I solved it. I took the different road of counting the images rendered  rather than testing the repeater/model directly.

```
it('should display four thumbnails of the nexus-s', function() {
  var imgsCount = element.all(by.css('.phone-thumbs li img')).count();
  expect(imgsCount).toBe(4);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who needs to know this.  Here's how I did it.

```
it('should display four thumbnails on the nexus-s page', function() {
      var images = element.all(by.repeater('img in phone.images')).count();
      expect(images).toBe(4);
    });
```

Comment: Just trying to understand your solution. What is the value of `element`?

Comment: @alljamin, `element` is a protractor alias for ElementHelper