# jasmine testing for elements by class or div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jasmine

I have some HTML that I want to test...

```
<div class="privacy-text">
    <a on-tap="goPrivacyPolicy()" class="disable-user-behavior">Privacy Policy</a> |
    <a on-tap="goTerms()" class="disable-user-behavior">Terms of Service</a>
</div>
```

In jasmine, I'm trying to see that the elements are present and visible.. but all I get are errors that my functions are not correct..  Am I supposed to use JQuery selectors for the `element()` calls??

```
it("should list a terms of service", function() {
  expect(element(by.css('.disable-user-behavior')).count()).toEqual(2);
});
```

Edit :

I have decided that these elements should have an unique ID so that I can pick them up individually.

```
 element(by.id('privacyPolicy1234')).count(); 

 TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test for the number of elements using Jasmine in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23583408/test-for-the-number-of-elements-using-jasmine-in-angularjs)

Comment: It's a possible duplicate. The answer is what you are looking for

Comment: if I want the unique elements then I should add the `id` attribute, correct @Elyasin ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my problem was due to trying to use the

```
.count()` on `element(...)
```

it only works on

```
element.all(...).count()
```

Thanks to the team behind protractor, they added this

```
it("should list a terms of service, privacy policy ", function() {
   var privacyElement = element(By.id("privacyPolicy1234"));
   browser.wait(function(){
       privacyElement .isPresent();},
       10000,"Element NOT found");
   expect(privacyElement.getText()).toContain("Privacy Policy");
   writeToLog("saw elements");
});
```